# what is the use of getWrappedDriver method in appium ?? can anyone please explain with an example?

Tags: android, selenium, selenium-webdriver, appium

I'm using Appium for mobile automation of our project apk file. I have used all methods present in Appium driver, but can't figure out this one..getWrappedDriver ??? Can anyone please explain the use of this method in detail with an example?

Sooner response would be much appreciated :-) :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you find a Selenium WebElement using WebDriver's method FindElement(), then you will get an object of type WebElement. If you want to do something with this element, then you usually need the WebDriver instance again. So if you e.g. have a sub-function where you want to do something with the element, then often you would need to pass in the element as well as the driver:

```
private void _DoSomethingWithElement(IWebElement element, IWebDriver driver)
{
    driver.WaitForElementToBeVisible(element);
    element.Click();
}
```

But this is not necessary, as the element "knows" the driver. This is what you use getWrappedDriver() for: Get the driver instance from the element instance. Example:

```
private void _DoSomethingWithElement(IWebElement element)
{
    IWebDriver driver = element.getWrappedDriver();
    driver.WaitForElementToBeVisible(element);
    element.Click();
}
```

Not that this does **not** work for elements generated with Selenium page factory. Very unfortunately!